# how to tokenize a text by nltk python

Tags: nltk, tokenize, cpu-word

i have a text like this:

```
Exception in org.baharan.dominant.dao.core.nonPlanAllocation.INonPlanAllocationRepository.getAllGrid() 
with cause = 'org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet'
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

i tokenize this text with word_tokenize in python and output is:

```
Exception
org.baharan.dominant.dao.core.nonPlanAllocation.INonPlanAllocationRepository.getAllGrid
cause
'org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException
could
extract
ResultSet'
Caused
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException
ORA-00942
table
view
exist
```

But as you can see, the second line outputs several words that are dotted together. How to separate these as a Word?!

i use this python code:

```
>>> f = open('001.txt')
>>> text = [w for w in word_tokenize(f.read()) if w not in stopwords]
```

and In fact, I want all words to be separated like this:

```
Exception
org
baharan
dominant
dao
core
nonPlanAllocation
INonPlanAllocationRepository
getAllGrid
cause
'org
hibernate
exception
SQLGrammarException
could
extract
ResultSet'
Caused
java
sql
SQLSyntaxErrorException
ORA-00942
table
view
exist
```

Comment: What exact output do you need? What exact code did you use?

Comment: code i use is :  f = open('001.txt')
text = [w for w in word_tokenize(f.read()) if w not in stopwords].   I want output like this: Exception
org
baharan
dominant
dao
core
nonPlanAllocation
INonPlanAllocationRepository
getAllGrid
cause
'org
hibernate
exception
SQLGrammarException
could
extract
ResultSet'
Caused
java
sql
SQLSyntaxErrorException
ORA-00942
table
view
exist

Comment: In fact, I want all words to be separated

Comment: Please add these details to the question.

Comment: Maybe all you need is a regex? `import re`, then use `print([w for w in re.findall(r'\w+(?:-\w+)*', f.read()) if w not in stopwords])`? The single quotes will be lost though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a simple way that use of RegexpTokenizer of nltk.tokenize like this:

```
>>> from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
>>> tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
```

The output after considering remove stopwords is as follows:

```
Exception
org
baharan
dominant
dao
core
nonPlanAllocation
INonPlanAllocationRepository
getAllGrid
cause
org
hibernate
exception
SQLGrammarException
could
extract
ResultSet
Caused
java
sql
SQLSyntaxErrorException
ORA-00942
table
view
exist
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
f = "Exception in org.baharan.dominant.dao.core.nonPlanAllocation.INonPlanAllocationRepository.getAllGrid() \
with cause = 'org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet' \
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist'"
s = ''
f_list = f.replace('.', ' ').split(' ')
for item in f_list:
    #print(item)
    s = s + ' ' + ''.join(item)+'\n'

print(s)
```

**output**

```
 Exception
 in
 org
 baharan
 dominant
 dao
 core
 nonPlanAllocation
 INonPlanAllocationRepository
 getAllGrid()
 with
 cause
 =
 'org
 hibernate
 exception
 SQLGrammarException:
 could
 not
 extract
 ResultSet'
 Caused
 by:
 java
 sql
 SQLSyntaxErrorException:
 ORA-00942:
 table
 or
 view
 does
 not
 exist'
```